# Print output in quotations linux

Tags: linux

How do i create a shell script in linux to redirect output to text file and print the output between quotation example "john brown"

Comment: The same way you would on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

```
some_command | sed 's/.*/"&"/' > output_file
```

This will execute `some_command` and send the output to `sed`.

The `sed` command will match everything on each line (`.*` means "any character, repeated zero or more times"), and enclose it in double-quotes (`&` means "the entire matching text").

The `>` operator redirects the output to `output_file`.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo \"Hi there\" > file
```

You can do the same inside a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo \"

# your commands and stuff here

echo \"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tee`.

```
echo "John Brown" | tee /tmp/file
```